# Retrieving user login time in SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion

I need to write a script that generates a report of users that have not logged into Tridion for 1 year. I know we can retrieve the modified dates and the users of all the files, but how would we track the login date of users who don't make any modifications, i.e. only read-only access?

Comment: Hi Wilson, thanks for joining SO and posting about SDL Tridion. would you consider committing to the Area 51 proposal for Tridion questions at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 8):

Look at the IIS logs for the Tridion 2011 application.  In there you should see requests for all the pages in Tridion by various users.  Some of the entries will look like this:

```
2012-09-20 00:48:53 ::1 GET /WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/TridionDashboard/TridionDashboard.aspx - 81 TRIDION\Administrator ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.89+Safari/537.1 200 0 0 48
```

From the item above you can see that the TridionDashboard page, i.e. the first page you get after logging in, was accessed by the TRIDION\Administrator user (yes, my Tridion VM is called "TRIDION" and I logon to it using the Administrator account).

So, what you need to do is make sure that the logs don't get overwritten once they fill up and get archived to a location where you can grab them and parse them.

The only info you require is the user name.  Simply throw it into some kind of a HashSet  data structure (that stores only unique keys) such that key is username and value is the timestamp.  I bet you can do all the parsing with a couple lines of code using Powershell (or if you use Cygwin a one liner using the grep command will also do the trick).

The logs are typically in %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles, but check your system to ensure that location hasn't been modified.

Answer (score 3):

I have never written Something like this, the only way I can think of achieving this is to create a GUI extension which adds AppData indicating login time to the User Object whenever they open the CME.

I don't believe there is an event triggered when the login occurs, otherwise I would suggest creating an even system.

You might consider reading this article by Nuno (http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/inheriting-metadata-on-organizational-items), it describes executing an action which is triggered by a user opening an item. My guess is that it would be triggered even when the user only has readonly access (but you would need to check this). If it is triggered on all read actions, you could update the user AppData whenever a user opens any IdentifiableObject in the CME. This would tell you when the user last viewed any item in the CME.

Hope that helps

Chris

Comment: I have written something like that, following the approach that Chris mentions (write something on Load). Just be careful that Load events fire _a lot_ and you have to make sure you're not killing the system with the overhead of writing this data somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Mihai blogged about this a while ago, here is the link, it has some code examples too: http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/capturing-users-last-login-date-into.html

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the Load event. This is called by pretty much every action in the GUI. As soon as anyone uses Tridion, the event is certainly called.
But be careful: you have to write super efficient code because otherwise it will slow down the system.

Comment: Mihai blogged about this a while ago, here is the link, it has some code examples too: http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/capturing-users-last-login-date-into.html

Comment: I think Mihai's blog is the answer! Will you change your comment into an answer so it can be accepted? Or let Mihai do it himself, of course..

Answer (score 0):

Tridion doesn't keep track of a "last modification made by this user", so you'll have to roll something yourself.

The first thing that pops to my mind is to write a [handler for the `Save` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072387/sample-event-system-code-for-tridion-2011-sp1) of `IdentifiableObject`. In that handler you can update an [Application Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10801337/209103) property on the user. The script can then simply loop over all users, get your AppData and determine which users have been inactive for more than a year.

Comment: I think you have missed the point - It IS possible to get a list of items that a user has modified, and from that it IS possible to get a date of the last time a user modified an item in the CMS. User1684360 is asking how he might tackle the challenge of logging when a user last logged into the CME, as several of the users only have read access to the CMS, and as such never edit any items. I don't believe there is an event associated with a user logging into the CMS, or  am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, I misread and then started over-engineering. :-) There indeed is no LogOn event, so a GUI extension would be the only thing I can think of for that. Or a ReadEvent on the User object. I never looked at the exact happenings of such an event, but fear it may fire too often. For example when somebody starts iterating all users.